# ILClone on Windows 2000

Tags: windows, shell32

Does anyone know of any issues with the ILClone() function on Windows 2000? Is it fully supported? MSDN says it runs on Windows 2000 but I have a user reporting that my program will not run on Windows 2000 because of that function.

**EDIT:** I was able to get a hold of a Win2K system and I can confirm the issue.

Shell32.dll version installed is **5.0.3700.6705**. The error message shown when running the program is: *The procedure entry point ILClone could not be located in the dynamic link library SHELL32.DLL*

Answer (score 0):

iirc ILClone was available on Windows 5, but it was exported from shlwapi.dll, so you had to load it using LoadLibrary & GetProcAddress() to be compatible.

Comment: Sweet. I'll try this and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Tried GetProcAddress() on a loaded shlwapi.dll, and also on a loaded shell32.dll, but neither worked. GetProcAddress(lib, "ILClone") returns NULL.

Comment: Apparently these functions were originally exported by ordinal.
That said, while ILClone is convenient, its an easy function to write.